# How to comment java file

Tags: java, oop

There is a way to comment the whole class (file) in java?

[image]

like here to comment BinaryTree class.

Comment: to press ctrl+a and ctrl+/  in  your ide

Comment: Another way to do it without using an IDE is: open the file and in the beginning  put /** and in the end put **/

Comment: thanks, that's helped alot :)

Comment: Could you mark as resolved the question?

Comment: Rename the file to a non-java suffix. `.java-disabled` Comes to mind.  This also keeps git history clean.

Answer (score 1):

You have some options to do it:

- **Without IDE:** open the file and in the beginning put **/**** and in the end put ****/**
- **Eclipse**: Ctrl + A (select all the file) and Ctrl +C
- **IntelliJ**: Ctrl + A (select all the file) and Ctrl + / (to comment)